# $p$-adic analogue of modular forms, upper half-plane, and $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

In the classical picture, there is the (complex) modular form, defined on the (complex) upper half plane, which is related to the (complex) $L$-function via the Mellin transform. As I have recently been aware of the notions of $p$-adic modular forms, $p$-adic upper half plane, and $p$-adic $L$-functions, I was thus wondering if there is a $p$-adic analogue of this classical picture which relates the three objects. If not, what would be a 'good/correct/conjectural/etc.' analogue in the $p$-adic setting? Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure the state of knowledge has moved far on since then, but there is a paper by Sally and Taibleson called [Special functions on locally compact fields](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392818) that was a very early attempt at starting to answer this sort of question.

Comment: The Sally--Taibleson paper looks like it's answering a slightly different question to me. They are working with complex-valued functions on a p-adic space, so this is actually more relevant to the "classical" theory of modular forms than the p-adic one, which is distinguished by the fact that one considers functions *from p-adics to p-adics*.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the comment! I looked at the paper, and indeed it is not what I have in mind for the same reason as mentioned by Loeffler. I guess what I was hoping to see, which is also mentioned in Loeffler's comment, are functions from a p-adic analogue of the upper half plane to a p-adic analogue of the complex numbers (the latter can probably be taken as C_p).

Answer (score 9):

The subjects of "p-adic L-functions" and "p-adic modular forms" are so closely intertwined that it's virtually impossible to talk about either one without immediately running into the other. Applications to p-adic L-functions have been baked into the theory of p-adic modular forms from the start (cf. Serre's paper [Formes modulaires et fonctions zêta p-adiques](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-37802-0_4) in the 1972 Antwerp proceedings, which introduces the definition of a p-adic modular form, and then immediately uses it to give a new construction of the Kubota–Leopoldt p-adic zeta function). There are numerous works (notably Mazur–Kitagawa, Greenberg–Stevens, multiple papers of Hida, etc.) devoted to this interplay between p-adic modular forms and p-adic L-functions.

The p-adic upper half-plane (in Drinfeld's sense) is a little less immediately related — p-adic modular forms are *not* defined as functions on it — but it does come up in the theory from time to time; Darmon's paper "[Integration on $\mathcal{H}_p \times \mathcal{H}$ and arithmetic applications](https://doi.org/10.2307/3062142)" is perhaps the first paper that comes to mind in this direction.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will check those papers you mentioned, but I was wondering if you could explain a bit more on perhaps some essential ideas of the interplay between p-adic modular forms and p-adic L-functions, so that I wouldn't get lost and could keep myself on the right track when reading these papers. Thank you so much!

Comment: Some people are never satisfied. What you are asking for now would be the content of an entire lecture course, and I don't give those in comment boxes (nor for free).

Comment: I am sorry if my last comment came out as inappropriate. As I am only a graduate student who knows little about this field, I wasn't aware of the vast content that my question may contain when I asked it, so I do apologize if my question asks too much. Still, I truly appreciate your answer and will start reading the references you mentioned. Thank you so much!

Comment: There's quite a few expository articles and lecture notes floating around the web on this; you might enjoy reading Chris Williams' notes https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/cwilliams/lecturenotes/lecture_notes_part_ii.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for another comment! I will read the notes alongside the papers you mentioned in the answer then.